# how to show upload image on ngx-dropzone-image-preview

Tags: angular

how can I show (API response)uploaded images when i use dropzone

on .html

```html
<div class="custom-dropzone banner-img" ngx-dropzone [accept]="'image/*'"
                                    (change)="onSelect($event)" matInput>
                                    <ngx-dropzone-label>
                                        Click or Drag a file to upload
                                    </ngx-dropzone-label>
                                    <ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview"
                                        *ngFor="let f of files" [file]="f" [removable]="true" (removed)="onRemove(f)">
                                        <ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }} ({{ f.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label>
                                    </ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
                                </div>
```

images response

```js
{
id: 30, path: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/Screenshot from 2020-06-24 01-22-14-20200721192851.png"}
}
```

Comment: Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Here's the idea, you need to convert you url into base64 format.

```
 convertToBase64(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function () {
          callback(reader.result);

      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);

  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.send();
  }
```

then sanitize it.

```
link = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/img/Screenshot from 2020-06-24 01-22-14-20200721192851.png"
 const sanitize = this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.RESOURCE_URL, this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(link));
```

after that push the code into ngx-dropzone-image-preview. Check the complete implementation.

```
 this.convertToBase64(sanitize, (dataurl) => {

      var arr = dataurl.split(','),
      mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
      bstr = atob(arr[1]),
      n = bstr.length,
      u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

  while(n--){
      u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }

      const a = new File([u8arr], "test.jpg", {type:mime});

      this.files.push(a)
    });
```